# pgAdmin III: ERROR: function postgis_full_version() does not exist

Tags: 11.04, sql

I'm running Natty:

Attempting to get *pgAdmin III* running. So I went to the pgAdmin [download section for Ubuntu](http://www.pgadmin.org/download/ubuntu.php)... but did not see Natty instructions.

So I downloaded the Natty [pgAdmin III .deb from Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pgadmin3/1.12.2-1/+build/2202258)

This fired up Ubuntu's Software Center. I installed. Everything worked.

I opened up *pgAdmin III* and connected to my local postGIS database successfully.

Now! I'm following along in the text **PostGIS in Action** and it tells me to execute:

```
SELECT postgis_full_version();
```

This of course gives the error, as per title:

```
ERROR:  function postgis_full_version() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT postgis_full_version();
           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

SQL state: 42883
Character: 8
```

Update: Furthermore, I ran the exact query in *phpPgAdmin* and got:

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  function postgis_full_version() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT postgis_full_version();
           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

In statement:
SELECT postgis_full_version();
```

This is why I've placed this in the Ubuntu SE - Similar results from *phpPgAdmin* and *pgAdmin III* suggest it's not an issue with the respective GUI, but rather...the OS?

Scoured Google, can't seem to find anything related...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though perhaps a convoluted method, pgadmin III was indeed installed correctly using the above method. I found the issue... You must call the postgis_full_version() function on a database that has been **PostGIS enabled**.

To enable PostGIS on a database, you must execute the postgis.sql and spatial_ref_sys.sql queries on that database via command line by navigating to your `<postgis>/<version>/contrib` directory and executing:

```
psql -d <db_name> -f postgis.sql
```

and

```
psql -d <db_name> -f spatial_ref_sys.sql
```

If you can't seem to locate these files, you can always go to your root and use the locate command:

```
cd /
locate postgis.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to go through all that trouble because
PgAdmin III is [packaged for Natty under universe](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/pgadmin3)

1. Uncomment the Universe sources in **/etc/apt/sources.list**
2. Run:

   apt-get update

   apt-get install pgadmin3

Comment: It's cool that you figured it out.